# Custom SQL in the django ORM: Filtering a list based off another filtered list in one query

Tags: python, django, orm

What i'm trying to do is retrieve a filtered list of CarModel objects where the carfield
is in a list of fields of another model, say the GasModel. But the set of GasModels must also be filtered out, to a list where a field in GasModel must equal another field from the CarModel (different field).

So pretty much I want to filter a list so that a field of that list is contained in a separate list of fields of a different model, and that list (of the second model) is also filtered (but by a different field of the first (car) model). I'd like for this to be all in one queryset call.

This is what I have so far, the error I belive is

```
WHERE anothergasfield = another_field_from_car_carmodel
```

Am I missing a FROM keyword or something? And if so where should it go?

```
CarModel.objects.extra(where = ['carfield IN (SELECT gasfield FROM\
    gas_gasmodel WHERE anothergasfield = another_field_from_car_carmodel)'])
      .order_by(...)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
CarModel.objects.extra(where = ['carfield IN (SELECT gasfield FROM\
    gas_gasmodel WHERE anothergasfield = carmodel.another_field_from_car_carmodel)'])
      .order_by(...)
```

Just replace the `carmodel` with the table name for `CarModel`. Usually is `{{ app_name }}_{{ model_name }}`.

You have nested `select` statement inside of which fields are from `gas_gasmodel` table, not from `carmodel` table.